# Custom map_meta_cap filter does not return ['do_not_allow']

Tags: php

I have created a custom role that only has access to certain pages and their children/parents. I have used `map_meta_cap` filter to solve this. However even though it goes through my function correctly it will not function properly, `return ['do_not_allow'];` is not working as intended and I don't know why, it seemingly does not do anything.

```
//Custom Roles (stored to db on theme activations)
add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'staby_add_theme_roles');
function staby_add_theme_roles() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['activated'])) {
        add_role(
            'test',
            __( 'Test', 'staby' ),
            array(
                'pages_id' => array(6911),
            )
        );
        $role = get_role('test');
        $role->add_cap('read');
        $role->add_cap('edit_pages');
        $role->add_cap('edit_published_pages');
        $role->add_cap('edit_others_pages');
        $role->add_cap('publish_pages');
        $role->add_cap('pages_restriction');
    }
}
    //Role cap for different pages
function staby_map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
    // // If the capability being filtered isn't of our interest, just return current value
    
    if ( in_array($cap, ['edit_pages']) ) {
        
        // First item in $args array should be page ID
        if (!staby_role_can_edit( $user_id, $args[0] ) ) {
            // User is not allowed, let's tell that to WP
            return ['do_not_allow'];
        }
    }
    
    // Otherwise just return current value
    return $caps;
}
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'staby_map_meta_cap', 10, 4 );

//See if role can edit correspondent page 
function staby_role_can_edit( $user_id, $page_id) {
    $page = get_post( $page_id );
   // let's find the topmost page in the hierarchy
   while( $page && (int) $page->parent ) {
     $page = get_post( $page->parent );
   }
   
   if ( ! $page ) {
     return false;
   }

   $user = new WP_User($user_id);
   if ($user->allcaps['pages_id']) {
       $user_pages = $user->allcaps['pages_id'];
       if (!in_array($page->ID, $user_pages)) {
            return false;
       }
   }
   
   return true;

}
```

The only thing I have noticed is that the `map_meta_cap` filter runs multiple times, and the `$args` variable is always empty but it somehow still retrieves the `$args[0]` (page id) in my custom function `staby_role_can_edit( $user_id, $page_id )` (but when I call it in that function it's `null`?). I have no idea why it's not working at all.

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks.

Update:

Tried with `user_has_cap` filter

```
    function staby_cap_filter( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
    
    //Bail out if role does not have restriction
    // Bail out if we're not asking about a post:
    if ( 'edit_post' != $args[0] || !$allcaps['pages_restriction']){
        $allcaps[$cap[0]] = false;
        return $allcaps;
    }
    if (!staby_role_can_edit( $args[1], $args[2] ) ) {
        $allcaps[$cap[0]] = false;
        return $allcaps;
    }
    return $allcaps;
 
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'staby_cap_filter', 10, 3 );
```

However even though it finds the correct page I don't know how to make it restrict access correctly.

```
$allcaps[$cap[0]] = false;
return $allcaps;
```

As you can see it sets the primitive capability to false if the user doesn't have access to the page.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct hook that you should use. Have you tried using the [`user_has_cap` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/) instead?

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried this and got it to work, kinda. It's really buggy, can't access admin dashboard, publish button almost works but it says "Submit for review" instead and no feedback that page has been updated. For some reason when you refresh the editorpage is completely blank. Basically it finds the correct page that you can edit but I don't know how to make it restrict access.

Comment: Your first `if` doesn't look right, so what are the `pages_restriction` and `pages_id`? Are they an array of post (parent Page) IDs? How are you setting the values and are you sure the allcaps array actually contains those keys?

Comment: @SallyCJ `pages_restriction` are a custom check with `add_cap()` and `pages_id` are the accessible pages for that role. I copied the answer on [user_has_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/). `var_dump($allcaps)` shows all the correct capabilities for my role. I'm uncertain how to use `$cap` though.

Comment: So you're doing this just for the `test` role and Pages (i.e. posts of the `page` post type), and that the `pages_id` would only contain top-level Pages where their `post_parent` is `0`? And I suggest you to use the `switch_theme` action instead of `load-themes.php`, to add the custom role, or do something like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/#comment-3194).

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes exactly the test role should be able to edit and publish the top page and all its children. Actually what would you do to improve my `staby_cap_filter`?

Comment: If you still need help, I'll post an answer in a couple of hours from now :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Yeah would be great! :)

Comment: @SallyCJ Alright so I hope you see this but I have another problem. The role also needs to be able to create posts (Not pages). Is this possible with the current setup? I tried adding 
`if ('publish_posts' === $args[0]) { return $allcaps; }` 
at the start of `staby_cap_filter`but it doesnt make a difference. I noticed that it returns `true` once on new page/post creation.

Comment: Check the update in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to make it restrict access correctly.

Try this, which uses  [`get_post_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/):

```php
function staby_cap_filter( $allcaps, $cap, $args, $user ) {
    // Get the current user's roles.
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;

    /* Do nothing if:
       1. The above roles doesn't include 'test', or
       2. edit_post is not the capability being checked, or
       3. The post ID was not specified, or
       4. pages_id is empty.
    */
    if ( ! in_array( 'test', $roles ) ||
        ( 'edit_post' !== $args[0] ) || empty( $args[2] ) ||
        empty( $allcaps['pages_id'] )
    ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // If the user being checked is the author of the post (which can be a custom
    // post type), then do nothing.
    if ( (int) $args[1] === (int) get_post_field( 'post_author', $args[2] ) ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }

    // Get the first ancestor of the current post that's being checked.
    $parent_ids   = get_post_ancestors( $args[2] );
    $first_parent = array_pop( $parent_ids );

    $allowed_ids = array_intersect(
        array( $first_parent, $args[2] ),
        $allcaps['pages_id']
    );

    // Disable the capability if the post ID is not in the allowed list.
    if ( empty( $allowed_ids ) ) {
        $allcaps[ $cap[0] ] = false;
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'staby_cap_filter', 10, 4 );
```

Additionally, I suggest you to use the [`switch_theme` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/switch_theme/) instead of `load-themes.php`, to add the custom role, or create a plugin and then do something like [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/#comment-3194).

### UPDATE

I added a post author check to the above function, see lines 19-23. So be sure to update your code.

As for your comment: "*The role also needs to be able to create posts (Not pages). Is this possible with the current setup?*"

In that case, then you need to ensure the role has the capabilities for editing posts, e.g. `edit_posts`, `edit_published_posts` and `publish_posts` like you can see below: <sub>(And actually, you didn't have to do `$role = get_role('test')` and `$role->add_cap()` to add the capabilities and instead, just define them via the below array..)</sub>

```php
add_role(
    'test',
    __( 'Test', 'staby' ),
    array(
        'pages_id'             => array( 6911 ),
        // capabilities for creating/editing posts
        'edit_posts'           => true,
        'edit_published_posts' => true,
        'publish_posts'        => true,
    )
);
```

So with that and the updated `staby_cap_filter()` function, users in the above role would now be able to create posts as well as edit them. But only non-private posts unless you added the relevant capabilities to the role.

---

However, the admin menu/UI for custom/other post types which for example has the `edit_posts` capability will also be visible to users in that role, and thus it might be easier for you to use [a plugin like User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) to manage the role and its capabilities, where you would be able to quite easily disable the role for certain post type's capabilities.

And particularly if you want to use a plugin like that, it might be better to add the `pages_id` as an [option](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/options/) (in the WordPress options/`wp_options` table) instead of a capability in the role.

#### So if you want to use a plugin to manage the user role

1. Remove the `add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'staby_add_theme_roles');` from your code and then use something like the following to add the "pages_id" option, but it's really up to you on how would you add/update the option:

   ```php
   // I used `init` just for testing.
   add_action( 'init', 'staby_add_pages_id_cap' );
   function staby_add_pages_id_cap() {
       if ( ! get_option( 'test_role_pages_id' ) ) {
           update_option( 'test_role_pages_id', array( 6911 ) );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then in the `staby_cap_filter()` function, add `$pages_id = (array) get_option( 'test_role_pages_id' );` at the top, and replace the `$allcaps['pages_id']` with `$pages_id`.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Works better than I expected it too, even in the admin pages! Would upvote if I could but need to get better rep. 

By the way, is there any difference in creating a plugin for things like [add_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/#comment-3194)? I have that set up in my theme's functions.php at the moment.

Comment: I'm glad it worked well for you! As for `add_role()`, I was just telling you to ensure not to unnecessarily re-add the role when it's already added, but the function itself works just the same whether you called it from within a standalone plugin or as part of a theme, just like `register_post_type()`. But see [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/#what-is-functions-php) and you would know if you should create a plugin or not :)